# How to setState() of a text field after handling an error in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a function called `LoginWithFb()`. The function has a try catch block:

```
void loginWithFb() async {
    try {
      var auth = AuthProvider.of(context).auth;
      print('Signing up with fb...');
      setState(() {
        _showProgressIndicator = true;
      });

      FirebaseUser user = await auth.signInWithFBAcc();
      uId = user?.uid;

      if (uId != null) {
        print('Signed in: $uId');
        widget.onSignedIn(user);
      } else {
        print('fb login cancelled');
      }

//    _showAlert(context);
      setState(() {
        _showProgressIndicator = false;
      });
    } catch (exception) {
      print(exception.toString());

      setState(() {
        _showProgressIndicator = false;


      });
    }
```

When the error is caught, I want to display message to the user. The message has to be in a text field and not via a dialog. At the moment I have an empty `Text('')` widget in my build method. I want to write text to the text widget when the error is caught..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use local variable for storing message and show it via Text widget

```
   String message = "";   
   void loginWithFb() async {
    try {
      ...
    } catch (exception) {

      print(exception.toString());

      setState(() {
         message = "Some error happens";
        _showProgressIndicator = false;
      });
    }
```

In widget:

```
Text(message);
```